# Add node in serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have one simple class:

```
public class A
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

And I want when I serialize:

```
<NodeSurrounded>
   <A>
      <Property>value</Property>
   </A>
</nodeSurrounded>
```

I am obliged to add an additional class to add the node NodeSurrounded?

Comment: What do you use for serializing?

Comment: XmlSerializer + StreamWriter

Answer (score 2):

Try following approach

```
A a = new A { Property = "value" };
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));

using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml"))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("NodeSurrounded");
    xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, a);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
}
```

We manually add the xml node.

Then, on deserialization, we also have to manually bypass this node.

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("A");
    a = (A)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new node.
Then use
XmlNode.AppendChild

to append to your NodeSurrounded node

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `ToXML()` and a `FromXML()` methods inside your class.

```
public string ToXML()
{
    return new XDocument(
                new XElement("NodeSurrounded"),
                    new XElement("A", this.Property)).ToString();
}

public void FromXML(string xml)
{
    var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    this.Property = document.Root.Element("A").Element("Property").Value;
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to use built-in XML serialization, (i.e. XMLSerializer). Creating `ToXML` and `FromXML` methods allows implement whatever, but if I'm not wrong, he wants to avoid this kind of coding and use some .NET code.